# VBA: Add values to an array based on a condition

Tags: excel, vba, match, dynamic-arrays

Imagine in sheet(4) i have the following, where D and E are the columns and 8 and 9 are the row number.

```
   D  E
8  1  1
9  B  C
```

Therefore, I want to compare those values with values of columns B and D from sheet(1) of same workbook. If the values are equal then I will bring the respective value of column G. For instance:

```
    B  C  G  
13  1  A  5
14  1  B  6
15  1  C  7 
16  2  A  8
17  2  B  9
18  2  C  10
19  3  A  11
20  3  B  12
21  3  C  13
```

I will check if sh4.cells(8,D) = sh1.cells(13,B) and if that is true i will check if sh4.cells(9,D) = sh1.cells(13,C). If both conditions are true, I will bring the value of column G which is 5 and store in the array.

The code I have written is below and I count with your help to see why its not working.

```
Dim d as integer
 d = 0
Dim c as integer
 c = 1
Dim refConcentrations as variant

If sh4.cells(8,3+c) = sh1.cells(13+d,2) Then
 If sh4.cells(9,3+c) = sh1.cells(13+d,3) Then
  If IsEmpty(refconcentrations) Then
   ReDim refConcentrations(1 To 1) As Variant
   refConcentrations(UBound(refConcentrations)) = sh1.cells(13+d,7).value
  Else
   ReDim Preserve refConcentrations(1 To UBound(refConcentrations) + 1) as Variant
  End If
 End If
End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but is it only column D and E in sheet(4) ? or is it growing to columns F and G, or the rows ?

Comment: Shai Rado, it can grow in rows and columns

Comment: in sheet(4) you can grow in Rows ?

Comment: Yes. It depends on the size of table from sheet 1. So yes I can

Comment: Ok, then I'm out of ideas right now, cause if in sheet(4) the data grows in collumns, while in Sheet(1) it grows in Rows, then I can check some logics. Id it just anywhere it wants, I dont have an idea right now how to come up with a solution

Comment: Shai Rado I will look into the solution you've presented and will find a way :D thanks for your effort

Comment: there is no problem to add more columns, but rows....

Comment: How different is it? I mean, if I work with cells positions its practically the same

Comment: adding columns all you need to do it modify `For ColSrc = 4 To 5 ` to whatever number of columns you have, adding more rows, how do you know which pair to compare ?

Comment: It may be solved with 2 loops right?

Comment: I don't know right now, if you show more options how the data in Sheet(4) can look like , maybe i'kk know if I can think of something

Comment: Actually it depends on the value of 2 variables from sheet 1 that makes the construction of all other sheets dynamic. Its a methodology application. So for you to understand this part, you must understand all the previous steps. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will add all "matching" values from sheet(4) and sheet(1), from column G to `refConcentrations` array. The code allows multiple "adding" to array in case of multiple matches in sheet(1).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MatchSheetsData()

Dim refConcentrations As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Integer, LastRow As Long
Dim ColSrc As Integer    

' Init array to a very large size on init >> will optimize at the end of the code
ReDim refConcentrations(1 To 1000) As Variant

' find last row with data in Column B at Sheet(1)
With Sheets(1)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With    
j = 1 ' init array element index

' looping through column D-E in Sheet(4)
For ColSrc = 4 To 5        
    For i = 13 To LastRow
        If Sheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets(4).Cells(8, ColSrc).Value Then
            If Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets(4).Cells(9, ColSrc).Value Then
                refConcentrations(j) = Sheets(1).Range("D" & i).Value
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

Next ColSrc

ReDim Preserve refConcentrations(1 To j - 1) ' <-- resize array to number of elements found

End Sub
```